# Python - List of dictionaries - Typeerror: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, list, dictionary, typeerror

The next code creates a list of dictionaries. The keys of the dictionaries are only integers and are generated by the random function, and the corresponding values are generated by the ord function. It works perfectly fine when I generate small sized lists(around 10, 20 or 30), but I keep getting the same error when I create big lists(around 100 elements), which I need to do.
In add
if pair[0] == key:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

The code is this:

```
import random
import math
def makeArray(Size):
    Arr = [None] * Size
    return(Arr)

def getNumericKey(key):
    hash = 0
    for char in str(key):
        hash += ord(char)
    return(hash)

def H(keyN,m):
    return(keyN % m)

def search(key, Size, table): 
    key_hash=H(getNumericKey(key),Size)
    if table[key_hash] is not None:
        for pair in table[key_hash]:
            if pair[0]==key:
                return(pair[1])
            else:
                for j in range(Size):
                    keyh=(key_hash+j)%Size
                    if keyh==(Size-1):
                        break
                    for pair1 in table[keyh]:
                        if pair1[0]==key:
                            return(pair1[1])
    return(None)

def add(key, value, table, Size):
    key_hash = H(getNumericKey(key), Size)
    pairkeyvalue = [key, value]
    if table[key_hash] is None:
        table[key_hash] = list([pairkeyvalue])
        return(True)
    else:
        for pair in table[key_hash]:
            if pair[0] == key:
                pair[1] = value
                return(True)
        for j in range(Size):
            keyh = (key_hash + j) % Size
            if keyh == (Size - 1):
                print('table llena', key_hash)
                break
            else:
                if table[keyh] is None:
                    table[keyh] = list(pairkeyvalue)
                    return(True)

a=int(input("Size of table: "))
table = makeArray(a)
lst = [0] * math.floor(a/2)
for i in range(math.floor(a/2)):
    lst [i] = random.randint(1,100)
print(lst)
for n in lst:
    add(n, getNumericKey(n), table, len(table))
print(table)
```

Comment: please post the traceback

Comment: Turn the int into a string

Comment: lst = [0] * math.floor(a/2)-- this line of code is also wrong, you cannot multiply list with a float

Comment: Actually, the floor function takes the closest integer from the operation.
If a = 100
Floor takes 50
If a = 5
Floor takes 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `add`, you want to change the line `table[keyh] = list(pairkeyvalue)` to `table[keyh] = list([pairkeyvalue])` or `table[keyh] = [pairkeyvalue]`. `pairkeyvalue` is already list, so `list(pairkeyvalue)` does nothing, but you want `table[keyh]` to be a list containing a list.

```
def add(key, value, table, size):
    key_hash = H(getNumericKey(key), size)
    pairkeyvalue = [key, value]
    if table[key_hash] is None:
        table[key_hash] = [pairkeyvalue]
        return True
    else:
        for pair in table[key_hash]:
            if pair[0] == key:
                pair[1] = value
                return True
        for j in range(size):
            keyh = (key_hash + j) % size
            if keyh == (size - 1):
                print('table llena', key_hash)
                break
            else:
                if table[keyh] is None:
                    table[keyh] = [pairkeyvalue]
                    return True
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jeremy McGibbon 
That solved the problem

Comment: No problem, glad to help!